# How to resolve TypeError after Angular CLI build

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular5, google-signin

I have integrated Google login Api in my project. It works fine at the development stage, and the application build was successful, without any error. But, when I run the build file, and try to login in my browser, I get the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'signIn' of undefined

My Component code

```
declare const gapi:any;

export class AppComponent {
    public googleInit() {
        let that = this;
        gapi.load('auth2', function () {
          that.auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
            client_id: 'CLIENT_ID',
            cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
            scope: 'profile email'
          });
        });
      }
    public auth2:any;
    loginGoogle(){
        let seed = this;
        this.auth2.signIn().then(function(res){
            console.log(res)
        });

      }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.googleInit();
      }
}
```

My Template File

```
<button (click)="loginGoogle()">Login</button>
```

How to solve the TypeError in my code? the above coding works fine in the development environment.

Comment: I believe your are missing a import in your angular-cli.json file that attach the auth2 lib to your project, on compilation

Comment: When do you assign `this.auth2` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
declare const gapi:any;

export class AppComponent {
    public googleInit() {
        gapi.load('auth2',  () => {
          this.auth2 = gapi.auth2;
          this.auth2.init({
            client_id: 'CLIENT_ID',
            cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
            scope: 'profile email'
          });
        });
      }
    public auth2:any;
    loginGoogle(){
        let seed = this;
        this.auth2.signIn().then(function(res){
            console.log(res)
        });

      }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.googleInit();
      }
}
```